Scanning as a method of learning?
What is the support, origin, or source for scanning as a method of learning? Scanning the text with the eyes without necessarily pronouncing or voicing the text, I've heard this mentioned as a way to learn Zohar, particularly from the Kabbalah Center. Is this method mentioned anywhere else in Judaism?

Please know that the Kabbalah Center is a scam organization that is shunned by the rest of the Jewish community.

@N.T. Thank you, yes, I'm aware of that. That's why I'm asking if this method has any accepted source in Judaism. Maybe it's a little like Tikkun Leil Shavuot where you have just the first three and last three verses of each Parashah? Or maybe could it be a case of being mevin davar mitokh davar (understanding one thing from inside another)? I'm puzzled.

In terms of fulfilling a positive commandment (Torah Study), the general rule is that it must involve action. The minimal action from Chazal is the movement of lips, which is associated with speech. There is a meditative practice involving lip movement without sound pronunciation. This is practiced by some in connection with the teachings of Avraham Abulafia. But it should be noted that this doesn't mean activities less than this are meaningless. Consider, for example, the prohibitions of looking at nakedness or even thinking words of Torah in a prohibited place like in a toilet.

When you say scanning, do you mean reading and comprehending, or just looking at the text?

@shmosel I think it could be either one of those but more important to this question if it's merely the latter.

Generally, the Jewish way is to pray audibly and to learn texts audibly. See for example Why do we need to daven out loud if G-D can hear our thoughts?
On learning texts audibly see the following (not a classic source but a modern article which is worth reading in full) https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/reading-torah-studying-torah/
Jewish Text Study Is Traditionally A Communal Activity by Barry W Holtz
Reading Jewish texts is not just a religious act, it is an act of communal identification and communication.
Here is an excerpt:
Jewish learning is carried on in a loud, hectic hall called the bet midrash (study house) where students sit in pairs or threesomes, reading and discussing out loud, back and forth. The at­mosphere is nothing like the silent library we are accustomed to. Read­ing in the yeshiva is conducted in a room with a constant, incessant din; it is as much talk as it is reading. In fact, the two activities of reading and discussion are virtually indistinguishable.
See also the passage referring to the Kabbalah Center's practice of "scanning" copied in my comment below.

How does this answer the question re scanning as a method of learning?

It takes the contrary view and focuses on the use of vocalisation as opposed to reading or scanning for Jewish learning

See too https://www.beliefnet.com/faiths/judaism/2004/02/keeping-kabbalah-jewish.aspx
and the quote from that article in my next comment.

"Likewise, the Kabbalah Centre's practice of "scanning" seems designed to ensnare the ignorant. Here is how one practitioner sums it up on the Centre's website: "Scanning is weird, amazing, and magical. I purchased the 'Book of Healing'. And just followed the simple instructions. You let your eyes just look at the Hebrew letters. You just sort of brush your eyes over the printed Hebrew words on the page. You absolutely do not have to understand or know anything about Hebrew or the meaning of the words. They tell you what to scan for whatever specific purpose you have a need for."

ensnare the ignorant yes may be convenient for them but doesn't necessarily invalidate it

BH
Look Gemara Sukkah 28b if it helps also first chapter Shar Yichud by Mittler Rebbe talks about difference between Surface vs in-depth learning

consider summarising what they say, as at the moment this is less of an answer and more of a comment.
